# Excel merging values in column B for rows with same column A

Tags: excel

I have excel table for example:

```
ColumnA      ColumnB

CompanyA        1
CompanyA        2
CompanyA        3
CompanyB        1
CompanyB        2
```

what i need to do with it:

```
ColumnA      ColumnB

CompanyA        6
CompanyB        3
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Look at pivot tables. It's what they are meant for.

Comment: Thank you, that is what i was looking for.